# Can I charge laptop with wire 20awg

Tags: power-electronics, wire, charge, laptop, awg

My laptop has a maximum power is **170W, 20V**, and I often use it with max power.
My adapter has a broken power jack and I must change the wire that supplies power for the charge.
I use wire **20awg**, the length of the wire is about **2 meters**, and the wire is **copper**, diameter of 1 thread of about 2mm.
So, Can I use this wire to charge and use for my laptop?

Thanks so much.

[image]

Comment: What wire loss did you calculate you will end up with?

Comment: I only replace this wire for my laptop's charge. I want to know that can this wire handle the maximum current for my laptop? Because I don't find the wire charge with size better than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My laptop has a maximum power is 170W, 20V

It's unclear if your laptop charger can adjust the output voltage for higher power or if it's fixed at 20 VDC.

Initially, I'll assume that your charger delivers 170 W output power with 20 VDC output voltage.

This makes the total current \$I_O=170/20=8.5 \text{A}\$.

From reference AWG tables we can see that a 20 AWG copper wire is rated for 5~6 Amps, and the resistance is ~50 mOhms/metre.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmQJmc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As can be seen from the schematic below, the total drop across the wires would be almost 1 V. Also the total loss would be \$P_W=I_O^2\cdot R_{wire} \cdot 2=7.2 \ \text{W}\$. That's a hell of a loss!

So no, 20 AWG is not suitable.

---

Note that the calculations above are based on an assumption that the 170 W output power is received with 20 VDC output voltage therefore a load current of 8.5 Amps will be taken continuously.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer.